# Output of strtok() gives different behaviour every time I run my program

Tags: c, linked-list, strtok

Part of my C89 programming task involves reading the contents of a text file, containing an unknown number of words on one line, into a linked list. The words are separated by whitespace. I think, enter strtok.

My function is not 100% complete yet but it is able to correctly grab words from a buffer (previously read in character-by-character with fgetc) and stick them in the 'word' field of a linked list node, and I'm just checking if I can print the words out again before continuing.

E.g. if: `here are some words in the user file\0` is the contents of the buffer then the output looks like this:

```
head->word = here
head->word = are
head->word = some
head->word = words
...
```

Which is as expected. However, sometimes upon running the output is a little weird, typically manifesting in words missing one or two characters from either the start or end, or both. Sometimes it seems as if a word gets chopped in two with parts of it across two lines of output. This is from the same executable! I've read several other threads over the last hour getting nowhere and am completely stumped - I figured I'd be better off fixing this issue first before continuing in case my whole approach needs changing.

My code is below and any help whatsoever is appreciated on this frustrating matter... time to fetch another Red Bull methinks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "nodestruct.h"

char** readUserfile(char** userFilename, int* numUserwords)
{
    /* Open user file for reading */
    FILE* userPtr = fopen(*userFilename, "r");

    char ch = (char)fgetc(userPtr); /* 'ch' temporarily stores input taken by fgetc() */

    int length = 0; /* Eventually the length of the file's line, +1 for a null terminator */

    char **userArray = NULL;

    /* Creating a temporary buffer to store the contents of the user file. The buffer is allowed to grow
    until it holds the contents of the file, as we are told the user file has all it's words on one line,
    separated by whitespace, however we do not know the total number of words preventing us from using
    fgets() to read in the line (unless we make an arbitrary decision on a very big 'size' argument) */
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 128;
    char* buffer = (char*)malloc( sizeof(char) * BUFFER_SIZE );

    /* Delimiter for call to strtok() below: the whitespace that separates words in the user file */
    char delim = ' ';
    const char* delimPtr = &delim;
    /* String to catch return value of strtok() so we can check if non-null (i.e. returns a word) or null
    (end the linked list at this word) */
    char* strtokReturn;

    /* Read user file: */
    /* While still contents to be read */
    while(ch != EOF)
    {
        if(length != BUFFER_SIZE)
        {
            buffer[length] = ch;
            length++;
        }
        else    /* Buffer is full, so realloc, doubling the size each time */
        {
            BUFFER_SIZE *= 2;
            buffer = realloc(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
            buffer[length] = ch;
            length++;
        }
        /* Read the next character. If EOF reached, the while loop condition will stop the read */
        ch = (char)fgetc(userPtr);
    }

    /* Trim the buffer to only contain the information that was read + '\0' */
    buffer = realloc(buffer, (sizeof(char) * (length+1)) );
    buffer[length] = '\0';

    /* Just a note in case the user file was empty */
    if(length == 0)
    {
        printf("Note: no words found in user file.\n");
    }

    /* Create a linked list containing all the words read by the above method */
    Node* head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    /* Enter the first word into the list - strtok() is used here to begin breaking up the contents of the
    buffer read previously into separate strings (words). The delimiter is the whitespace character ' ' */

    strtokReturn = strtok(buffer, delimPtr);
    strcpy(head->word, strtokReturn); 
    printf("head->word = <<%s>>\n", head->word);
    head->next = NULL;

    strtokReturn = strtok(NULL, delimPtr);
    strcpy(head->word, strtokReturn); 
    printf("head->word = <<%s>>\n", head->word);
    head->next = NULL;

    strtokReturn = strtok(NULL, delimPtr);
    strcpy(head->word, strtokReturn); 
    printf("head->word = <<%s>>\n", head->word);
    head->next = NULL;

    strtokReturn = strtok(NULL, delimPtr);
    strcpy(head->word, strtokReturn); 
    printf("head->word = <<%s>>\n", head->word);
    head->next = NULL;

    strtokReturn = strtok(NULL, delimPtr);
    strcpy(head->word, strtokReturn); 
    printf("head->word = <<%s>>\n", head->word);
    head->next = NULL;

    strtokReturn = strtok(NULL, delimPtr);
    strcpy(head->word, strtokReturn); 
    printf("head->word = <<%s>>\n", head->word);
    head->next = NULL;

    strtokReturn = strtok(NULL, delimPtr);
    strcpy(head->word, strtokReturn); 
    printf("head->word = <<%s>>\n", head->word);
    head->next = NULL;

    strtokReturn = strtok(NULL, delimPtr);
    strcpy(head->word, strtokReturn); 
    printf("head->word = <<%s>>\n", head->word);
    head->next = NULL;

    strtokReturn = strtok(NULL, delimPtr);
    strcpy(head->word, strtokReturn); 
    printf("head->word = <<%s>>\n", head->word);
    head->next = NULL;

    strtokReturn = strtok(NULL, delimPtr);
    strcpy(head->word, strtokReturn); 
    printf("head->word = <<%s>>\n", head->word);
    head->next = NULL;

    strtokReturn = strtok(NULL, delimPtr);
    strcpy(head->word, strtokReturn); 
    printf("head->word = <<%s>>\n", head->word);
    head->next = NULL;



    free(head);
    head = NULL;

    free(buffer);
    buffer = NULL;

    fclose(userPtr);
    return userArray;
}/* End readUserfile() */
```

The output (pardon the length, but in the interests of full disclosure):

```
[Danyal@DanCentos assign]$ ./wordfixr userfile.txt
Spellrc opened/read successfully.
Dictionary file opened successfully.
Dictionary read successfully.
head->word = <<here>>
head->word = <<are>>
head->word = <<some>>
head->word = <<words>>
head->word = <<in>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<user>>
head->word = <<file>>
head->word = <<and>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<whole>>
[Danyal@DanCentos assign]$ ./wordfixr userfile.txt
Spellrc opened/read successfully.
Dictionary file opened successfully.
Dictionary read successfully.
head->word = <<h>>
head->word = <<r>>
head->word = <<ar>>
head->word = <<som>>
head->word = <<words>>
head->word = <<in>>
head->word = <<th>>
head->word = <<us>>
head->word = <<r>>
head->word = <<fil>>
head->word = <<and>>
[Danyal@DanCentos assign]$ ./wordfixr userfile.txt
Spellrc opened/read successfully.
Dictionary file opened successfully.
Dictionary read successfully.
head->word = <<here>>
head->word = <<are>>
head->word = <<some>>
head->word = <<words>>
head->word = <<in>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<user>>
head->word = <<file>>
head->word = <<and>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<whole>>
[Danyal@DanCentos assign]$ ./wordfixr userfile.txt
Spellrc opened/read successfully.
Dictionary file opened successfully.
Dictionary read successfully.
head->word = <<here>>
head->word = <<are>>
head->word = <<some>>
head->word = <<words>>
head->word = <<in>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<user>>
head->word = <<file>>
head->word = <<and>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<whole>>
[Danyal@DanCentos assign]$ ./wordfixr userfile.txt
Spellrc opened/read successfully.
Dictionary file opened successfully.
Dictionary read successfully.
head->word = <<here>>
head->word = <<are>>
head->word = <<some>>
head->word = <<words>>
head->word = <<in>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<user>>
head->word = <<file>>
head->word = <<and>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<whole>>
[Danyal@DanCentos assign]$ ./wordfixr userfile.txt
Spellrc opened/read successfully.
Dictionary file opened successfully.
Dictionary read successfully.
head->word = <<here>>
head->word = <<are>>
head->word = <<some>>
head->word = <<words>>
head->word = <<in>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<user>>
head->word = <<file>>
head->word = <<and>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<whole>>
[Danyal@DanCentos assign]$ ./wordfixr userfile.txt
Spellrc opened/read successfully.
Dictionary file opened successfully.
Dictionary read successfully.
head->word = <<here>>
head->word = <<are>>
head->word = <<some>>
head->word = <<words>>
head->word = <<in>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<user>>
head->word = <<file>>
head->word = <<and>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<whole>>
[Danyal@DanCentos assign]$ ./wordfixr userfile.txt
Spellrc opened/read successfully.
Dictionary file opened successfully.
Dictionary read successfully.
head->word = <<h>>
head->word = <<r>>
head->word = <<ar>>
head->word = <<som>>
head->word = <<words>>
head->word = <<in>>
head->word = <<th>>
head->word = <<us>>
head->word = <<r>>
head->word = <<fil>>
head->word = <<and>>
[Danyal@DanCentos assign]$ ./wordfixr userfile.txt
Spellrc opened/read successfully.
Dictionary file opened successfully.
Dictionary read successfully.
head->word = <<here>>
head->word = <<are>>
head->word = <<some>>
head->word = <<words>>
head->word = <<in>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<user>>
head->word = <<file>>
head->word = <<and>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<whole>>
[Danyal@DanCentos assign]$ ./wordfixr userfile.txt
Spellrc opened/read successfully.
Dictionary file opened successfully.
Dictionary read successfully.
head->word = <<here>>
head->word = <<are>>
head->word = <<some>>
head->word = <<words>>
head->word = <<in>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<user>>
head->word = <<file>>
head->word = <<and>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<whole>>
[Danyal@DanCentos assign]$ ./wordfixr userfile.txt
Spellrc opened/read successfully.
Dictionary file opened successfully.
Dictionary read successfully.
head->word = <<here>>
head->word = <<are>>
head->word = <<some>>
head->word = <<words>>
head->word = <<in>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<user>>
head->word = <<file>>
head->word = <<and>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<whole>>
[Danyal@DanCentos assign]$ ./wordfixr userfile.txt
Spellrc opened/read successfully.
Dictionary file opened successfully.
Dictionary read successfully.
head->word = <<here>>
head->word = <<are>>
head->word = <<some>>
head->word = <<words>>
head->word = <<in>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<user>>
head->word = <<file>>
head->word = <<and>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<whole>>
[Danyal@DanCentos assign]$ ./wordfixr userfile.txt
Spellrc opened/read successfully.
Dictionary file opened successfully.
Dictionary read successfully.
head->word = <<here>>
head->word = <<are>>
head->word = <<some>>
head->word = <<words>>
head->word = <<in>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<user>>
head->word = <<file>>
head->word = <<and>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<whole>>
[Danyal@DanCentos assign]$ ./wordfixr userfile.txt
Spellrc opened/read successfully.
Dictionary file opened successfully.
Dictionary read successfully.
head->word = <<here>>
head->word = <<are>>
head->word = <<some>>
head->word = <<wor>>
head->word = <<s>>
head->word = <<in>>
head->word = <<the>>
head->word = <<user>>
head->word = <<file>>
head->word = <<an>>
head->word = <<the>>
```

Just n.b., I changed the printf statements to encapsulate the printed string in some brackets to make sure there were no invisible characters as seen in another thread, but as you can see just the word is printed.

Once again, thanks in advance for any help, I really appreciate it, and am truly grateful to live in a time where a place like stack overflow exists for free.

Comment: Where's the definition of `Node`? Are you allocating memory for `head->word`?

Comment: Yes, pardon me, the declaration for the node is in the "nodestruct.h" header file:

`#define MAX_STRING_LEN 51

typedef struct Node
{
 char word[MAX_STRING_LEN];
 struct Node* next;
}Node*`

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `strtok` should a null-terminated string.
`strtok` considers any element of that string to be a valid delimiter.  If you want just the one delimiter, use a length-1 string:

```
strtokReturn = strtok(buffer, " ");
```

Without a `'\0'` to terminate your `delimPtr`, `strtok` is looking at the bytes that happen to follow `delim`.  And apparently it sometimes finds an `'e'` char before a `'\0'` char and ends up treating `'e'` as another delimiter.

Comment: What you're saying makes a lot of sense, I changed the function to reflect this:

`char delim[] = " \0";
const char* delimPtr = delim;`

However, when I run the program this time it appears the same result is produced. I should note though that the value of an int-pointer telling me how long my linked list was changed from 20 (one too long) to 19, which is what it should be (number of words in the original text file).

Comment: Curiously... I've noticed that valgrind reports no errors on leaked memory, which is odd as I haven't properly freed my newly-created linked list yet. When my unfinished function just had a 'head' node I had a `free(head)` at the end to free it, but now that I've confirmed to have a linked list of 19 nodes, and I left in the single `free(head)` without freeing the whole list, I'm surprised that valgrind hasn't told me I've lost as many blocks...